# Multiplying and dividing many variables in one line in bash

Tags: bash, variables, math, division, multiplication

I'm wondering if there is a way to easily do this expression in bash:

(2*a*sqrt(3))/2, where a is some variable that I loop over. Is there a way to condense this all into one expression? So far I did this:

```
for a in 1.1 2.2 3.3
do
    sqrt3=$(echo "sqrt (3)" | bc -l)
```

Then I tried multiple things:

```
my_val = $(echo "(2*${sqrt3}*${a})/2" | bc)
```

Two expressions:

```
first = $((2 * sqrt3 * ${a}))
second = $first/2
```

However, none of these work. It doesn't give an error, but it also doesn't print anything when I try to print the expression out. If it isn't possible to condense this into one expression, is there still a way to do this? Thanks!

edit: Trying this now -

```
for a in 1.1 2.2 3.3
do
     my_val = $(echo bc <<< "scale = 3; 2 * $a * sqrt(3) / 2")
```

The main problem is that it's not saving as a variable. I tried this too:

```
 my_val = $(echo "scale = 3; 2 * $a * sqrt(3) / 2" | bc)
```

Comment: Something like `for a in 1.1 2.2 3.3; do bc <<< "scale = 3; 2 * $a * sqrt(3) / 2"; done`?

Comment: Why does it have to be done in one line? Is there a newline shortage?

Comment: It doesn't have to be done in one line, just wondering if there's a clever way to do it as such. If not, it's fine.

Comment: Benjamin: Is there a way to save this all to a variable? Thanks!

Comment: `my_val = $(echo "(2*${sqrt3}*${a})/2" | bc)` is a command. It tries to execute `my_val` with the rest as parameters. Remove the spaces around `=`. It should be `my_val=$(echo "(2*${sqrt3}*${a})/2" | bc)`.

Comment: Bash arithmetic is integer arithmetic, so you're going to have problems with `sqrt(3)`.  Korn shell can do floating point arithmetic, I believe.

Comment: For future reference, you can answer all your questions about basic shell script usage at [**ShellCheck**](http://www.shellcheck.net/). Give it a go before posting and you will likely be able to answer many of your questions on your own.

Answer (score 3):

Shell scripts distinguish variable assignments from command invocation by looking at space after a word.

The `=` sign in your variable assignment is surrounded by space. In shells, this is not an assignment but a command invocation.

This:

```
my_val = $(echo "(2*${sqrt3}*${a})/2" | bc)
```

Should be changed to this:

```
my_val=$(echo "(2*${sqrt3}*${a})/2" | bc)
```

With spaces around `=`, shell thinks `my_val` is a command, `=` is the first parameter, and the result of the calculation is the second parameter.